# Service Fabric - How to enable BackupRestoreService on my local dev cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-on-premises

I would like to get the backup and restore related functionality working inside the service fabric explorer for my local dev cluster. Any action I take related to backup/restore in the cluster manager ui throws a service not found exception currently, I believe due to the backup and restore service not running on the cluster.

I can't find any documentation pertaining to configuring the local dev cluster. The standalone cluster steps don't seem to apply. I have attempted to use sfctl to get the cluster configuration with `sfctl sa-cluster config` but the operations times out against my local dev cluster. I've tried the analogous Get-ServiceFabricClusterConfiguration from powershell module and get a timeout there as well.

For the time being I have built a code based backup and restore, but I really like the service and would like to see what I can do with it locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with cluster version `7.0.470.9590`

Verify BackupAndRestore service is available in your installation.
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\__FabricSystem_App{random-number}\BRS.Code.Current` folder should exist with the correct binaries.

Change your local cluster config.
Your clusterconfig is located under: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup`

So if your dev cluster is single node unsecure, you can change: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\OneNode\ClusterManifestTemplate.json`

In the `"addOnFeatures"` tag you can add `"BackupRestoreService"` example:

```
"addOnFeatures": [
   "DnsService",
   "EventStoreService",
   "BackupRestoreService"
]
```

Under `"fabricSettings"` you then add the configuration for the backup and restore service:

```
{
    "name": "BackupRestoreService",
    "parameters":  [
        {
            "name": "SecretEncryptionCertThumbprint",
            "value": "......YOURTHUMBPRINT....."
        }
    ]
}
```

After these steps you can reset your dev cluster from the system tray. (Right click the service fabric icon => Reset Local Cluster)

When your cluster is restarted you can verify if the service is running by opening the cluster dashboard and open the system services.
[image: local dev cluster with backuprestore service]

*You can use this approach to configure other system services as well.*

**Note: updating your SDK may result in losing the changes made to your cluster config.**

Comment: Thank you! Is this process documented anywhere official?

Comment: It’s based on [on premise cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server) combined with the install location of the SDK